# Is Yam also known as Nubia?

Tags: ancient-egypt, africa, geography

Harkhuf, an Egyptian official, set out for a place called Yam, which [a chronicle states was far south of Egyptian boundaries](http://www.britannica.com/place/Nubia). But where exactly was Yam? Was Yam later called Nubia? Are Yam and Nubia the same thing?

Harkhuf was an official who lived during the sixth dynasty, serving under  [Merenre I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merenre_Nemtyemsaf_I) and [Pepi II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepi_II_Neferkare). The story of his expeditions is preserved in the [inscriptions in his tomb](http://www.reshafim.org.il/ad/egypt/texts/harkhuf.htm).

Answer (score 7):

This is apparently quite a controversial topic, as covered in this [article](http://www.academia.edu/5646190/Cooper_Julien._Reconsidering_the_Location_of_Yam_Journal_of_the_American_Research_Center_in_Egypt_48_2012_1-22):

> The location of Yam as attested in Old Kingdom sources has been the
>   subject of extensive debate, much of which is covered in O’Connor’s
>   comprehensive treatise.  In this thesis O’Connor argued for an Upper
>   Nubian location, similar to the previous conclusions of Priese and
>   Edel, with the modiﬁca-tion of placing Yam further upstream in the
>   region of the Fifth Cataract and Shendi-Butana reach as opposed to the
>   Third Cataract and Kerma region preferred by Edel.  The most recent
>   synthesis of the Harkhuf material with a view to locating Yam was by
>   Obsomer, who placed the toponym in the area of Kerma. **Almost all
>   recent works have invariably followed Edel or O’Connor, accepting an
>   Upper Nubian location for Yam**

However, the author of this piece attributes the equation of Yam and northern Nubia with an unfortunate tendency to assume any place name south of Egypt must be Nubian:

> This argument of course does not aim to suggest, with any certainty or
>   precision, a location for Yam within a ﬁnite area. Rather it argues
>   that a Western Desert location of Yam, near the Gebel Uweinat, or
>   Ennedi, concords well with much of the textual and archaeological
>   evidence. Broadly, the evidence suggests that Yam could be approached
>   by going west and south from Egypt, via the oases and Abu Bal-las
>   trail, or south and then west via the Nubian Nile and North West
>   Sudan. The evidence is certainly too ambiguous to support a Nubian
>   location and to construct arguments based on this location would be
>   hazardous and premature. **Such previous attempts at localising Yam
>   reﬂect a broader tendency to place many unknown “southern” toponyms on
>   the Nubian Nile, with little or no evidence speciﬁcally favoring such
>   locations.**

I'm far from an expert, so I can't adjudicate here. Check out Julien Cooper's ["Reconsidering the Location of Yam"](http://www.academia.edu/5646190/Cooper_Julien._Reconsidering_the_Location_of_Yam_Journal_of_the_American_Research_Center_in_Egypt_48_2012_1-22) for the full argument.

Comment: Wow thank you for all the information, I'm more knowledgeable about this topic now

Answer (score 2):

If the report that he brought back a Pygmy is correct, that constrains the possible area to the tropical [Great Lakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_Great_Lakes) area in the central and western half of central Africa. Basically the area at the latitude of Lake Victoria, from there west.

[image]

Now if they did this in the usual Egyptian idiom: going further up the Nile, then it would be somewhere nearish [Lake Victoria itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Victoria), as that is the Nile's source.

The only other reasonable location in that era would have been the rift valley chain of lakes. Any other route I believe would require traversing tropical forest on foot, which looks far easier on a map than it is in actuality.

Comment: ahh interesting, thank you for your insight